# batch file: if else when comparing number

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, windows-server-2008

I just have a simple if - else statement in a .bat file running on windows server 2008. I just can't get it to work. It couldn't even open the command window. What am I missing?

```
IF 1 EQU 1 (
    Echo yes 
)ELSE(
    Echo no
)
```

Comment: Add a `pause` at the end of your code. Your script should be working. I'm guessing it just closes too quickly for you to notice it.

Comment: Spaces are significative in Batch files. Use `) ELSE (` instead of `)ELSE(`.

Comment: sorry, i have pause in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Aacini mentioned, spacing is important. Try this code; it works for me.

`@echo off
IF 1 EQU 1 (
    @echo yes 
) Else (
@echo no
)
@pause`

Hope it helps!

*As a side note, I do not believe you have to change your echos to be like mine. I just do that because that's the style I prefer.